# Fourier transform, Heaviside Step function

Tags: fourier-transform

I was solving this exercise:
Given the function
$$ P(x) = \Theta(x)e^{-x}$$
where $\Theta(x)$ is the Heaviside function. I need to find the expression of:
$$ f(x) = \int \int P(x_1)P(x_2)\delta(x-x_1-x_2)dx_1dx_2$$
First of all, I recognized that the double integral is the convolution of $P(x)$ with itself, $f(x) = P(x) \ast P(x)$. Therefore I used the Fourier transform, applying the well-known property:
$$\mathcal{F}[f\ast g](k) = \sqrt{2\pi}\hat{f}(k)\hat{g}(k) $$
which, in our case, reduces to:
$$\mathcal{F}[f](k) = \sqrt{2\pi}(\hat{P}(k))^2 $$
Now some questions started arising: our function can be written as:
$$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}
$e^{x}, x >0 \\
0, x<0 
\end{array} \right.
$$
But the Fourier transform's domain of integration is $]-\infty,+\infty[$
So how do I make sure that the integral of the fourier transform *behaves well*, namely do I need to consider an approximated form like the following:
$$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \left[ \int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon} P(x) + \int_{+\epsilon}^{\infty} P(x) \right]$$
Now what I did is restrain the domain of integration to $[0,\infty]$ and calculated:
$$\hat{P}(k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x(ik+1)}dx = ... = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{ik+1} $$
So I thought that maybe I could get away with this:
$$ \hat{P}(k)  = \left\{ \begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{ik+1}, x>0 \\
0, x <0
\end{align*} \right.$$
But this doesn't make much sense. I then checked the solution and found out that my professor doesn't make any domain restrictions, in fact, he only says that:
$$ \hat{P}(k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{ik+1} \tag{1}$$
I thought this was clearly wrong since it doesn't take into consideration that the step function presents a jump discontinuity at $x=0$ and just accounts for when $x>0$. I tried finishing the exercise by adopting $(1)$ and what I found is this:
$$ \hat{f}(k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{(ik+1)^2}$$
By using the antitransform I finally get:
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{ikx}}{(ik+1)^2}dk = \frac{1}{2\pi}I$$
Now I solved this integral as I usually do, namely the residue theorem:
I consider the trivial complex extension of the integrand:
$$f(z) = \frac{e^{izx}}{(iz-i^2)^2}$$
which has a second-order pole at $z = i$.
I then considered the two cases $x < 0, x> 0$. When $x$ is positive I can choose a standard contour(a semi-circumference of radius $R$) that encloses the pole and reduces to $I$ on the real axis when we take the limit $R \to +\infty$. Doing all the calculations (which I'll leave out) I obtain:
$$ I = 2\pi i Res(f,z=i) = 2\pi x e^{-x} $$
When $x$ is negative, I instead choose the same contour but in the $\Im(z)<0$ semi-plane. But this contour does not enclose any pole, therefore, from the residue theorem, we get:
$$I = 0, x<0$$
Therefore I wrote the solution in the following way:
$$ f(x) = \Theta(x)x e^{-x}$$
I checked the solution and the expression I just obtained is indeed correct.
So my professor was right all along I suppose? The transform of $P(x)$ is unique and represented by $(1)$. And somehow everything turns out smoothly when solving the complex integral. It is as though the Fourier transform of $P(x)$ *adapts to our initial piecewise smooth function*, allowing us not to make any distinction for $x \ge 0$ and for $ x<0$.
I might not have the necessary mathematical background to understand a complete and thorough answer, but I'd like to get a deeper insight into this anyway. Any help or answer will be obviously well-received.

Comment: Why don't you just use the definition of convolution, $(f*g)(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(y) \, g(x-y) \, dy$?

Comment: Could you be more specific? I used the fact that the initial double integral is a convolution, but I can't see where I'd need to use its definition again

Comment: You are supposed to calculate $P*P$. You can do this directly, $$(P*P)(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(y) \, P(x-y) \, dy$$ instead of going via the Fourier transform.

Comment: The exam is focused on using the  Fourier transform to solve PDEs and other problems, like this. I checked the solution written by my professor and he used the same exact strategy as me. That doesn't mean that this is the only or best way to solve this, but I'm somewhat required to use the Fourier transform, since I'll be tested on it. Nevertheless I calculated the integral and it does indeed gives the right result: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}H(y)e^{-y}H(x-y)e^{x-y}dy = ... = xe^{-x}H(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, note that $\hat{P}(k)$ can't depend on values of $x$, because it is a function of $k$ only; indeed, the Fourier transform maps the variable $x$ to a conjugated variable $k$, so that $x$ disappears in the transformation $P(x) \mapsto \hat{P}(k)$ because of the integration with respect to $x$.

Secondly, when calculating the integral
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} \theta(x)e^{-x}e^{-ikx} \,\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^\infty e^{-(1+ik)x} \,\mathrm{d}x = \left.-\frac{e^{-(1+ik)x}}{1+ik}\right|_{x=0}^{x=\infty} = \frac{1}{1+ik},
$$
$x$ stays positive, since the domain of integration is reduced to $\mathbb{R}_+$ because of the Heaviside function, that is why you must ignore the case $x < 0$.

Finally, let's recall that an integrand vanishing at some points on the domain of integration doesn't lead necessarily to a vanishing integral $-$ another good example being the characteristic function $-$, because the integral depends on all the points of the domain of integration. In consequence, you can't make an argument such as $f(x) = 0$ for some $x$ $\Longrightarrow$ $\int f = 0$; the latter case would mean that $f \equiv 0$ on the whole domain of integration.